# What is alt-n used for in bash?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> returns a `:` and apparently is for forward-search, but how do you use it?

Comment: @Jesse_b *left* alt

Comment: @Jesse_b, I think it boils down to localisation, in my spanish keyboard I have to press *left alt (altgr)+ñ* to get `~`, but *left alt+n* gives me `:` like OP.

Comment: @Jesse_b Found it. Though it would be good to know what combination is for other layouts (like yours).

Comment: @Jesse_b Are you using vi mode?  I'm using emacs mode.

Comment: @paradroid following my answer, when it goes bak to `:`, hit backspace and try again

Comment: @guillermochamorro: That just seems to return to the previously typed text and just repeats the same behaviour.

Comment: @paradroid I'm giving up for now, it just seems to work and the not.

Comment: What I can confirm is that when it works, navigates the *arguments*, not the *history*

Comment: @guillermochamorro Looks like we have an answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> / <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> bindings are configured as

```
$ bind -p | grep '\\e[np]'
"\en": non-incremental-forward-search-history
"\ep": non-incremental-reverse-search-history
```

which seems to match your configuration.

When you searched backwards with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> or <kbd>↑</kbd> and your position is not at the very end of your history, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> to search forward in your history.

Example:

```
echo   # Enter
ls -la # Enter
```

Then press <kbd>↑</kbd> twice, and your cursor is behind `echo` again.
Now press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>, enter `ls`, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and your cursor is at the beginning of `ls -la`.

Testing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> is easier as you don't have to go backwards in your history first. It works the same way.

Comment: Could you explain why I can navigate trough the *arguments* with Alt+n? When it works

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with _arguments_. To repeat searches in one or the other direction you can `bind` keys to `non-incremental-forward-search-history-again` and `non-incremental-reverse-search-history-again`.

Comment: Example: `echo foo` →foo, `ls` *alt+n* →`ls foo`

Comment: Isn't that [yank-last-arg](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-History.html#index-yank_002dlast_002darg-_0028M_002d_002e-or-M_002d_005f_0029), e.g. `echo foo`, `ls` _alt+._ → `ls foo`? On my system it's _alt+._ or _alt+\__

Comment: must be my keyboards acting strangely then. Thanks

Comment: My bindings are vanilla Debian with US keyboard. You can check your current settings with `bind -P | grep -v 'not bound'` (or lowercase `-p`).

Comment: Hello. `Alt p` can work but `alt n` can't? After entering the `alt n` there will be `:`, but whatever I input and press `enter` key, nothing will show.